# make the jexcel javascript spreadsheet responsive to screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, grid, responsive, spreadsheet

I am trying to use Paul Hodel's "The Javascript Spreadsheet" [click here](https://bossanova.uk/jexcel/v3/)

I have to specify width for each columns in colWidths. Spreadsheet is not viewable in different computer screens. Is it possible to make width of cells automatic to fit screen?
(I am using a older version of jexcel jquery plugin)

```
$("#grid1").jexcel({
colHeaders: ['Column 1','Column 2','Free Text'],
colWidths: [120,100,100],
columns: [
    { type: 'dropdown', source: TestData },
    { type: 'dropdown', source: TestData2, filter : filterData },
    { type: 'text'}
]
});
```

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue. I don't have a solution for you, but I was thinking of detecting the viewport, or div width then calculating the column widths based on a percentage of the viewport. Haven't tried it yet, but will offer this as a solution if I get anywhere.